# how to magnify a peak in matplotlib?

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, plot

I have a relatively simple problem. I have a set of data which has a peak in certain position. To plot it more clear, I want to multiply the data just around the peak. How to do so? As an example, I would like to multiply all values between  11 < x < 17 (which has  has y > -0.1) by a factor of 2. In my real data I have a condition on y-value e.g y > y0.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(1, 20, 100)
y = np.sin(x)/x

plt.plot(x,y,'-ob',lw=2,markersize=12)

plt.show()
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but you can use `np.where` to select specific indexes in an array, which correspond to a conditional (i.e.  `11<x<20`).

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(1, 20, 100)
y = np.sin(x)/x

plt.plot(x, y, '-ob', lw=2, markersize=12)

i = np.where( (x>11) & (x<20) & (y>-0.1))  
y[i]*=2

plt.plot(x, y, 'g', lw=2)
plt.show()
```

**EDIT**
Also, see @hitzg  comment about directly creating a binary mask. Therefore the code can be shortened to:

```
y[(x>11) & (x<20) & (y>-0.1)]*=2
```

[image]

Comment: The list comprehension is superfluous. You can add the condition on y in the where statement and then use `y[i] = y[i]*2`

Comment: Doesn't the Op only want to do that only if the y value meets a condition?

Comment: Exactly, so you can do `i = np.where( (x>11) & (x<20) & (y>-0.1))`, right?

Comment: Actually, there is no need for using `np.where`. It returns the indices where the condition is met, but you can directly use the binary mask (which you create anyways): `i = (x>11) & (x<20) & (y>-0.1)`

Comment: Thank you very much! it solved my issue. For my real data, I have 2 set of Fourier data to plot together, one has a pronounced zero peak and the other has two peaks which are smaller. If i plot all on the same axes, the minor peaks are hard to see. If i plot the minors on twin axis, they look on the same scale of central peak which is misleading. So I decided to plot the minors on the same axis but with magnified minor peaks. That was my reason for this Q and what I wanted to accomplish!

Answer (score 2):

With numpy arrays you can use binary masks. So `x < 11` will create an array of booleans, which you can use as a selection mask. Since you have multiple conditions you have to use `np.logical_and`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(1, 20, 100)
y = np.sin(x)/x
selection = np.logical_and(x > 11, x < 17, y < 0)
y[selection] = y[selection]*2

plt.plot(x, y, '-ob', lw=2, markersize=12)

plt.show()
```